# mail send successfully but Invalid address: error occur

Tags: php

I'm getting an invalid address error while running the PHP script

When I send the mail I am getting the error `Invalid address:` but mail send successfully...

Comment: My crystal ball says the problem is on line 15 of your script. If I'm wrong, I guess you'll have to post your code.

Comment: You probably have an invalid Email address. The mail will send successfully but will bounce back.  We will need more information though! What PHP script? Where do you see the invalid address message?